# FileProvider.GetUriForFile () throwing Exception. Cannot find configured root

Tags: android, xamarin

Here is my code in which I am trying to create a ContentUri so I can call a pdf viewer.

~ provider which IS inside `<Application>` and `<authority>` definitely matches package name

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.company.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

~ xml/filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="assets" path="Library/OfflineAssets/"/>
</paths>
```

~ .cs where I have the exception

```
var dir = "/data/data/com.tripleplay_services.triplesport/files/../Library/OfflineAssets/xamarin_documentation1_v1.pdf";
var newFile = new File(dir);
if(newFile.Exists ()) {
    var contentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Context, "com.company.fileprovider", newFile);
}
```

BANG!

Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.company/Library/OfflineAssets/xamarin_documentation1_v1.pdf

I'm doing everything by the book. I am stuck and cannot continue.

[Here is where the exception is thrown](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java#FileProvider.SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile%28java.io.File%29). I have no idea what is in `mRoots.entrySet()` in order to crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the source code I found that the Provider is trying to match /data/data/com.package/files/Library/OfflineAssets to /data/data/com.package/../Library/OfflineAssets

So basically my understanding for the file directory for android wasn't correct.

Make sure that whatever the directory you have saved your files in after data/data/com.package/files/ matches in your `<files-path>` path attribute.

~ Updated `<files-path>`

`<files-path name="assets" path="../Library/OfflineAssets/" />`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (in my app I was trying to call a camera instead of a PDF viewer) but later on I find out to have a typo in my code. 
The typo was in AndroidManifest.xml, precisely into the  tag at the line "authorities".

For me,

```
android:authorities="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.fileprovider"
```

doesn't work (when I call the camera instance, the app crashes) but if i delete "file" and replace that string as following:

```
android:authorities="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.provider"
```

my app runs smoothly (the app takes the photo, stores it, and gives back a preview to the activity in the client app).

Does your app also have the same issue ?